# loop trough foreignKey objects in HTML with UpdateView

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views

I am in process of writing UpdateView Class form , I am using inlineformset_factory to get ForignKey objects and its works , my issue is that i would like to iterate all ForignKey with HTML for displaying all its objects , and i am don't really know how to achieve it , since all objects i refer it , form. as declared in my forms.py so my question is someone could help me with given view and form how to, in HTML should i iterate my ForignKey objects

Please advice

Thanks

my code is shown below
my views.py Update view

```
class TaskIdUpdateView(UpdateView):
taskidformset = inlineformset_factory(MainTask,ChildTask, fields=('task_description','task_info','task_complete',
'sub_task','task_precent_complete','task_due_date','task_assign'))
model = MainTask
template_name = "taskid_update.html"
form_class = TaskUpdateForm
```

forms.py class form

```
 class TaskUpdateForm(ModelForm):

    TASK_STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('ST', 'STARTED'),
    ('NS', 'NOT STARTED'),
    ('IP', 'IN PROGRESS'),
    ('PA', 'PAUSED'),
    ('CO', 'COMPLETED'),
    ]
    INPUTֹTIMEֹFORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y',
'%Y/%m/%d',       # '10/25/2006'
'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M',
'%m/%d/%y',
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S']       # '10/25/06'

    #Main Task objects
    task_title = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Task Title'}))
    global_task_info = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Task Description'}))
    due_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False, input_formats=INPUTֹTIMEֹFORMATS, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'picker'
        }))
    global_task_assign = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= UserProfile.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'} ))
    task_status = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=TASK_STATUS_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    complete = forms.BooleanField( required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'type':'checkbox', 'class':'custom-control-input', 'id':'switchcomplete'}))
    overall_precent_complete = forms.IntegerField(widget=(forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'min':'0', 'max':'100', 'value':'50', 'class':'range-slider__range', 'id':'PreRange'})))
    task_location = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    #Child Tasks objects
    task_description = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Sub Task Description'}))
    task_info = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Sub Task Description'}))
    task_complete = forms.BooleanField( required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'type':'checkbox', 'class':'custom-control-input', 'id':'switchcomplete'}))
    sub_task = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Sub Task Description'}))
    task_precent_complete = forms.IntegerField(widget=(forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'min':'1', 'max':'100', 'value':'50', 'class':'slider', 'id':'myRange'})))
    task_due_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=INPUTֹTIMEֹFORMATS, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'picker'
        }))
    task_assign = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= UserProfile.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'} ))    




    class  Meta:


        model = MainTask
        fields = ['task_title',
            'global_task_info',
            'due_date',
            'global_task_assign',
            'task_status',
            'complete',
            'overall_precent_complete',
            'task_location',
            'global_task_assign',
            'task_status',]


        taskidformset = inlineformset_factory(MainTask,ChildTask, fields=('task_description','task_info','task_complete',
    'sub_task','task_precent_complete','task_due_date','task_assign'))
```

update.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html'%}

{% load static from static %}


{% block content %}
<!--accordion css-->
<link href="{% static 'css/range.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="conatainer">

    <div class="col text-center py-5">
        <form action="" class="" method="POST">
        <h3 class="mt-3 text-left">Update Task </h3>
  <hr>
            <p class="text-muted text-left">Update Itom task</p>

            {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}


        </form>

    <!-- Error messaging -->
    <div id="errors">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>There were some errors in the information you entered. Please correct the following:</p>
            <ul>
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.errors %}<li>{{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Error messaging -->
{% endif %}

<div class="input-group mt-3 mb-3 mr-auto">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-book-medical"></i></span>
        </div>
        {{ form.task_title}}
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
        </div>
        {{form.global_task_info}}
      </div>

     <!---date time picker-->
     <h6 class="text-left">Task Due Date</h6>
     <div class="input-group date mb-3 col-3">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
      {{ form.due_date }}

    </div> 
    <!--end of date time picker-->
     <!---Task Location-->

    <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3 col-8">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i></div>


          {{form.task_location}}

      </div>
    </div>

   <!--End Of Task Location-->
    <!---user assign-->
     <h6 class="text-left">Assign  Task to IT member</h6>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3 col-8">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>


          {{form.global_task_assign}}

      </div>
    </div>

   <!--End Of User Assign-->
   <h6 class="text-left">Set Task Status</h6>
   <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3 col-4">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">

        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-caret-square-right"></i></div>
    </div>
      {{form.task_status}}

    </div>

    <div class="range-slider mb-4">
        <h6 class="text-left">Set Task Global Progress</h6>
        {{form.overall_precent_complete}}
        <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
      </div>

        <h4 class="mt-3 text-left">SubTask Section </h4>
  <hr>
  <!---subtask section-->
  <div id="accordion">
    {{formset.task_description }}


    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-left bg-secondary">
        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!---End subtask section-->
    <div class="col text-left">
    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-white mt-2"><span><i class="fas fa-database"></i></span> Create Task</button>
  </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```